# Code without errors but app crushes when trying to run it. Swift in XCode

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a code that looks perfectly fine. It creates a CollectionVew which should (hopefully at the end) look like e-shop app. No errors are shown in the code.

But when I try to run it my app crushes.

 What does this error message means and how can I make it right?

```
import UIKit

//private let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionCell"

struct CollectionCell {
             var image: String
    var oldPrice: Double
    var buy: String
    var newPrice: Double
    var itemName: String
}


class FirstCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var goods: [CollectionCell] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        
        let cellWidth : CGFloat = collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - 10
        let cellheight : CGFloat = collectionView.frame.size.height / 3
        let cellSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth , height:cellheight)
      
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
        
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
        layout.itemSize = cellSize
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
        goods = createGoods()
    }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return goods.count
   
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
        cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: goods[indexPath.row].image) //картинка
        cell.oldPriceLabel.text = String(goods[indexPath.row].oldPrice) //старая цена
        cell.newPriceLabel.text = String(goods[indexPath.row].newPrice)//новая цена
        cell.buyButton.image = UIImage(named: goods[indexPath.row].image) //картинка для кнопки "в корзину"
        cell.itemNameLabel.text = goods[indexPath.row].itemName // имя продукта
        return cell
    }

    private func createGoods() -> [CollectionCell] {
        
        var goods: [CollectionCell] = []
        goods.append(CollectionCell(image: "shopping", oldPrice: 1000, buy: "shoppingcart", newPrice: 500, itemName: "Sweater"))
        goods.append(CollectionCell(image: "shopping-2", oldPrice: 2000, buy: "shoppingcart", newPrice: 1000, itemName: "Black boots"))
        goods.append(CollectionCell(image: "shopping-3", oldPrice: 3000, buy:"shoppingcart", newPrice: 1500, itemName: "Suede black boots"))
        goods.append(CollectionCell(image: "shopping-4", oldPrice: 4000, buy: "shoppingcart", newPrice: 2000, itemName: "Winter boots"))
       
        return goods
    }
}
```

this is how error massage looks

```
Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x7fff864aa0e8) to 'Sb_Hw_10.FirstCollectionViewCell' (0x10dfa6108).
2021-12-04 12:43:21.526974+0200 Sb_Hw_10[59915:2377738] Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x7fff864aa0e8) to 'Sb_Hw_10.FirstCollectionViewCell' (0x10dfa6108).
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/ksenia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sb_Hw_10-dscfvcrqcotfsrgznhzflrpdtzim/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/ksenia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sb_Hw_10-dscfvcrqcotfsrgznhzflrpdtzim/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x7fff864aa0e8) to 'Sb_Hw_10.FirstCollectionViewCell' (0x10dfa6108).
CoreSimulator 776.4 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (D4658EE6-D13F-4656-861B-841F192C6D3F) - Runtime: iOS 15.0 (19A339) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
(lldb)
```

I have separate file for my CollectionView cell. It looks like that:

```
import UIKit

class FirstCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
  
    @IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var oldPriceLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var newPriceLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buyButton: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UILabel!
    

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to update `self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")` so that you are registering  `FirstCollectionViewCell`. Change the code that registers your cell to  `self.collectionView!.register(FirstCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")`

Comment: You are registering a UICollectionViewCell, `register(UICollectionViewCell.self, ...)` but  dequeus a `FirstCollectionViewCell`. Register your custom cell type instead `register(FirstCollectionViewCell.self, ...)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This worked! But now I get error in this line " self.collectionView!.register(FirstCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell") " with error text Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value . What is that? Thank you!

Comment: I assume collectionView is nil, have you connected the outlet properly in the storyboard?

Comment: To complete @JoakimDanielson , did you check the type of cell in interface builder ?